# Interface class with nested classes in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write up an interface class which also contains other classes but i am getting an error when i do so but not sure what is wrong:

**Interface:**

```
export interface Languages{
   static English = class{
        id: number,
        section:number,
        name: string
   },
   static Chinese = class{
        id: number,
        section: number,
        name: string
   }
}
```

Both `static` and `English` are showing errors stating: `[ts] Property or signature expected.
[ts] Cannot find name 'English'.`

Comment: There's no `static` in an interface. An interface describes how the instance looks like. If you want to describe static members/methods you need to create a different interface to represent that, like you have with [Array](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L1111) and [ArrayConstructor](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L1294) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces is a contract, not an implementation. Your `English` and `Chinese` members are instances which is exactly what an interface **cannot** support. They are also static, which is also incorrect on an interface. You could refactor it like this:

```
export interface Languages{
   English: Language;
   Chinese: Language;
}

export interface Language {
    id: number;
    section:number;
    name: string;
}
```

A better design would be to use a dictionary or a list with a lookup especially if this is a non-fixed size list where languages may be added later. Something like this for example:

```
export interface Languages{
   getLanguageByCode(isoCode:string): Language;
   getLanguageById(id: number): Language;
   allLanguages: Language[];
}
```